# jQuery validations not working in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem.
The client is claiming that a prize signup form I built for them is not working in IE 7.
It works in IE 8 just fine which they agree about, but in IE 7 it doesn't. (luckily they don't care about IE 6).
I was hoping someone could help me debug it since I don't have access to a machine with IE 7 (I work on a Mac).
The page is here:
http://www.fuchscorp.com/midamerica/prizes/prize.signup.php

When you click the Submit button in IE 7 it just doesn't work.
Don't worry about submitting information as the site isn't live (so, no...you won't be winning any prizes).

If someone could please help me debug this and figure out what's going on that would be amazingly helpful.

Comment: PS if you turn on compatability mode in IE8 you can see it "not" work.

Comment: @Pselus: It doens't work in compatibility view either, maybe you can do a bit of debugging with the dev tools whilst in that mode?

Comment: Awesome.  I had no idea I could do that.
Thanks guys!

Comment: id be interested to know what is broked. i dont have ie8 here though. let us know what the fix was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the validate library for jQuery... but I don't see where you "hook" in your button to "submit" the form?

My guess would be that you need a `type="submit"` attribute on your button element... or IE7 is getting messed up because your `id` is `Submit`, and IE has issues with elements in a form named the same as methods.. e.g. `submit()`

So try adding the attribute and/or changing the id/name.

Comment: WINNER!
It was the `type="submit"` that was missing.
Thanks for that, I was wracking my brain trying to figure out what was wrong.
The "hook" for the validate is the .validate method on the Form element.  But apparently for it to work in IE7 it has to have type='submit' on the button so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it sucks, but as a web developer, you should be able to test all target platforms yourself.  I too am working from a Mac, but Windows and IE are parts of our business reality.  Either invest in a cheap PC (a couple hundred will get you what you need) or install [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (it's free!) and whatever versions of Windows you need (you could also run Windows via Bootcamp if you wanted).

Also, there is a free Windows program called  [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) that allows you to run instances of IE 5.5, 6, 7 and 8, regardless of what version of (the real) IE you have installed.  The program is ugly and slow, but it gets the job done.